# Type mismatch counting list F#

Tags: f#

Im trying to understand why this code errors, but it makes no sense to me. It should work I believe since in else condition I just re enter the function again until n & index are equal. Im trying to get the third element of the list.

```
let rec elem index n list =
  match index, n, list with
  | (i,n',head::tail) when (i = n') -> head
  | _ -> elem (index+1, n, tail)
     
elem 0 2 ["a";"b";"c"]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple problems with your code on the "catch-all" line.
First, you are trying to call the function with a single tuple parameter instead of with 3 separate parameters. The call should look like

```
  elem (index+1) n tail
```

But a bigger problem is that `tail` is not defined for this case. This means there's something wrong with your algorithm and you should fix this.

Comment: I rewrote the code as you suggested, but not it says that the elem function is not defined.

```

let rec elem (index, n, list) =
  match index, n, list with
  | (i,n',head::tail) when (i = n') -> head
  | (_, _, head::tail) -> elem (index+1) n tail     

elem 0 2 ["a";"b";"c"]

Comment: @TheManthis the formatting broke in the comment, and it's essential for F#, so hard to tell what went wrong. But it looks like you now added the parentheses to the function definition: why? it still should be `let rec elem index n list`, not `elem (index, n, list)`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm dunno why the code formating does not work when replying in stack overflow, anyway I understood the problem & here is the reason:

In the code above I called  **elem (index+1, n, tail)**. Turns out that this is a function that takes in a single parameter called a Tuple, however declared function takes in 3 parameters **elem index n list**, thus the type mismatch error.

Problem solved, thank you!

**Working exampe:**

```
let rec elem index n list =
  match index, n, list with
  | (i,n',head::tail) when (i = n') -> head
  | (_, _, head::tail) -> elem (index+1) n tail     
 
elem 1 2 ["a";"b";"c"]
```